# Multi domain SSL not working with www on SAN

Tags: iis-7.5, ssl-certificate-errors

I am using godaddy multi domain SSL on windows server 2008 with IIS 7.5. My main website www.abc.org working fine with www and non www but other domain ex.

DNS Name=www.abc.org
DNS Name=abc.org
DNS Name=www.abc1.com
DNS Name=www.abc2.es
DNS Name=www.abc3.com
DNS Name=www.abc4.com
so abc1.com to abc4.com not working with non www.

please help me about this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`example.com` is a different domain from `www.example.com`. `www.` is just a subdomain.

Certificates are only valid for domain names that they are specified for. Your certificate states `abc.org` and `www.abc.org` both as valid domains, but for your other domains, only `www.xyz.com` is specified, so it will only work with those.

As such, you will have to aquire a new certificate with the domain names both with and without `www.`, or a wildcard domain like `*.example.com`, which will be valid for the domain itself, and all of its subdomains.

Comment: dear sir @mzhaase
Thanks for responce but all domain are difrent and that working fine with www but not working without www.  Only 1st dmain (abc.org)working with www and non www.
There is no sub domains.

Comment: www IS a subdomain.

Comment: so what is solution for it

Comment: As in the answer, get a certificate that lists both www.abc1.com and abc1.com or alternatively *.abc1.com.